# TexMaker minted package, there is no output in pdf file

Tags: texmaker, minted

The minted package was used but the code blocks did not appear in the pdf file in TexMaker

```
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{csharp}
string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
/*
Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
circle of diameter $d$.
*/
const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}
```

The following is the setting of TexMaker

[image: Commands]
[image: Quick Build]

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Look at the .log, is there an error? Please complete your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @CarLaTeX, It is hard to find the error in the log file, but I found the error in the building process on TexMaker, and I fixed the issue by making a new link to pygmentize. Thank you!

Comment: You're very smart, good!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, Thank you, I am a LaTeX newbie and this is my first time using minted package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Quick Building the `.tex` file, I found the error

[image: pygmentize error]
And I realised that may be something was wrong on the path of `pygmentize`, so on my Macbook I checked the path of `pygmentize`,

```
$ which pygmentize
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pygmentize
```

And try to make a link

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo mv pygmentize pygmentize.bak
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pygmentize pygmentize
```

The issue is fixed.